# Что означает выражение "сирота казанская"?

Tags: фразеология

Кто-нибудь знает откуда пошло выражение "сирота казанская"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это выражение уходит корнями во времена Ивана Грозного, когда князья казанского ханства принимали христианство, чтобы добиться почестей от русского царя. Причем, мурзы в письмах к царю именовали себя "сиротами". Именно поэтому выражение "сирота казанская" всегда употребляется в ироничном смысле: тот, кто притворяется несчастным.

Answer (score 1):

При взятие Казани в октябре 1552 г. Иваном lV (Грозным), на 3-й день после штурма, повелел царь выкатить в центр площади старую арбу. И стали воеводы с опричниками мимо неё прогонять поочерёдно всё мужское население города, оставшееся в живых. Тем кто ростом вышел выше колеса арбы, отсекали голову тут же. В живых остались лишь дети 11-ти лет и менее. Сказал тогда им Царь: "Ходите в землях всяких и скажите, что нету боле ханства Казанского". И пошли они помиру за руку по 3-7 сирот, гурьбою. Люди, видя их на околицах своих селений, говорили: "СИРОТА КАЗАНСКАЯ идёт". Помогал им всякий, кто едой, кто одёжей, а кто и ночлегом. Долго бродили ещё они, а может и доселе в пути...(А НЕ ПО СЛОВАРЮ ДАЛЯ ЭТО ИЗРЕЧЕНИЕ!!!)

Comment: Ссылку на источник можно?

Comment: Этот вариант совершенно не объясняет негатива в значении фразкологизма.
Я тоже слышал о похожей, только акценты там были расставлены совершенно по-другому. Среди бродивших по Руси "казанских сирот" 9 из десяти были обычными попрошайками, не имющими ничего общего с пострадавшими от жестого царя. Плюс ко всему псе такие попрошайки, и казанские и неказанские, еще любили использовать икону Казанской Божьей матери.
Отношение у народа к ним было соответсвующее.  
Найду источник - выложу.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно правильно связывают происхождение фразеологизма с Казанью и ее населением. Ещё правильнее - с татарами, поступившими на службу к русскому царю. Но здесь есть некоторые нюансы. Татары были народом, практиковавшим многожёнство, и в одной семье могло быть несколько десятков сыновей от разных жён. А ещё для восточных народов в древности вообще была характерна очень жёсткая борьба за власть и имущество (естественно, речь идёт о правящей элите, которой было что делить). До тех пор, пока был жив глава семейства, он держал всех своих сыновей в повиновении, но, как только он умирал, братья начинали жестокую междоусобную резню, уничтожая как друг друга, так и всё мужское потомство в семьях братьев. Были случаи, когда убивали даже младенцев, чтобы не дать им возможность вырасти и отомстить. Поэтому те братья, которые даже не надеялись победить в этой бойне, едва услышав, что отец умер, спешно собирали свои семьи и имущество и бежали на Русь, где просили царя принять их в своё подданство, потому что теперь они - сироты, и их некому защитить. Как правило, это были люди вполне взрослые, женатые, знатные и очень богатые, но, принижая своё состояние, они рассчитывали получить больше милостей и благ. Поэтому и "сирота казанская": отнюдь не бедный человек, пытающийся казаться беднее, чем он есть.

Answer (score -1):

Сирота - самоназвание средневекового русского крестьянина до XVI века (указано академиком Зализняком, специалистом по письменным источникам древней Руси). "Казанская сирота" - фразеологизм, утративший свой изначальный смысл (см. работы академика Покровского).

Comment: Ссылочками поделитесь? Здесь не принято ссылаться на "см." И в чем был "утраченный смысл"?